# How to Execute single GET request multiple time with different set of Headers & then need to validate response as well using java API automation

Tags: java, api, rest-assured, web-api-testing

This is my code where I am using headers. I wasn't to execute same login API GET request with multiple set of headers and then need to validate response as well .

```
// API Test for Login
@Test(priority = 1)
public void GetLoginAPI() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
    header.put("auth-id", prop.getProperty("authid1"));
    header.putAll(header());
    httpResp=restClient.getResult(prop.getProperty("LoginURL"), header);
    
    //Status code Json String & Headers
    JSONObject respJson = TestUtil.staCodeJsonStringHeaders(httpResp);
    String idValue = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(respJson, "/user/id");
    String uidValue = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(respJson, "/user/uid");
    String locationValue = TestUtil.getValueByJPath(respJson, "/user/location");
    System.out.println("Value of type : "+idValue);
    System.out.println("Value of date : "+uidValue);
    System.out.println("Value of date : "+locationValue);
    Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(idValue), 319);
    Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(uidValue), 20190807);
    Assert.assertEquals(locationValue, "bangalore");
}
```

Comment: If you have a definite number, you can make those an array and use a loop. So on each loop increment to pass the equivalent value.

Comment: @karikevinod Thanks for the update 
but in this case, there is not only a single header we have different headers and i want to do using data-driven or something like Using Excel
any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using Testng

option 1- using dataprovider
for example

```
@DataProvider(name = "data-provider")
    public Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
        return new headers[][] { { "data1" }, { "data1" } };
    }
 
    @Test(dataProvider = "data-provider")
   public void GetLoginAPI(String header) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
        // Now use multiple header for GET request
    }
```

Option 2-
Use Hash map to store header and  add a loop and use it

```
HashMap<Integer, String> headervalues = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
headervalues.add("data 1)
headervalues.add("data 2) etc
```

and then using loop you can use multiple headers.

Option 3-
Using Excel use apacahe POI and then write down readExcel function and pass those values to your script.
Refer https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-excel-file-in-java